# snackbar is not showing above bottommodalsheet in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am opening a bottom model sheet, and want to implement a functionality that whenever I click on a icon, I get a snackbar. So i implemented it, but whenever I am clicking on the button, snackbar is coming under the bottom modal sheet, like when you lower the bottom model sheet, you can see snackbar popped there in previous screen. I want that snackbar should show above the modal sheet, visible to user while sheet is up. Please help me on this.

Here is the code -

```
class RouteItems extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;
  final NodeElement data;

  RouteItems({required this.index, required this.data});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  SvgPicture.asset(
                    'assets/icons/road-straight-line-top-view.svg',
                    height: 15,
                    width: 80,
                  ),
                  SvgPicture.asset(
                    filterRoutesIcon("${data.node?.type}"),
                    height: 30,
                    width: 30,
                  ),
                  SvgPicture.asset(
                    'assets/icons/road-straight-line-top-view.svg',
                    height: 15,
                    width: 80,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
                child: Container(
                  //height: 60,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.625,
                        child: Text(
                          '${data.node?.name}',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
                          //overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        data.eta!.getFormattedDate('hh:mm a, d MMM'),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0, color: colorDarkGrey),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                  SnackBar(
                    content: Wrap(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Bus is scheduled to arrive at ${data.eta!.getFormattedDate('hh:mm a, d MMM')} Bus is scheduled to depart at ${data.etd!.getFormattedDate('hh:mm a, d MMM')}'
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Icon(
                    Icons.timer,
                    size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.04,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    getStoppageTime(data.stoppage??0),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 10,
                      color: popUpLightTextColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```